How might my API be receiving an incorrectly formatted ISO 8601 timestamp
I have an iOS/Android app sending data to the Python backend.
In both apps, the user selects a date and time from a picker, and it is sent to the server:
Android:
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
URL url = new URL("https://example.com/api/test?distance=" + distance + "&date=" + formattedDate);

iOS:
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: date)
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/test?distance=\(distance)&date=\(formattedDate)")!

On the server, this is interpreted as follows:
date = request.GET.get('date', None)
if date:
    journey_date = datetime.fromisoformat(date)

I've just had a weird error come through, where the server is receiving the date in an unexpected format:
ValueError at /api/test/
Invalid isoformat string: '2024-05-20T3:38:12.711\u202fPMZ'

Basically the time looks like it is AM/PM format, rather than 24 hour.
In all the testing I've done so far, I've never come across this. Assuming the user has not sent a manual request to the endpoint (e.g. via Postman), and that they have just used the app UI, how might the date be received in this format when the specified format was yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'?
Update:
The user agent suggests it's coming from the iOS app.

First, don’t hardcode Z as a literal in your format pattern string. It’s an offset of 0 and needs to be formatted as an offset, or you will likely get an incorrect result. Second, \u202f is a narrow non-breaking space. How and why your app sent that I can’t tell.

Also for your sanity please abandon SImpleDateFormat. It was a notorious troublemaker of a class and has fortunately been outdated the last 10 years. In Java on Android use java.time, the modern Java date and time API for all of your date and time work.

On iOS use ISO8601DateFormatter

Assuming the user has not sent a manual request to the endpoint (e.g. via Postman), ... To me it would seem no unreasonable hypothesis that they may have. Or some left-over test code in a corner of your app where you didn’t look.

It's definitely a valid hypothesis, but I think it's unlikely in this scenario given the people using the app. The user agent also suggests it's coming from the iOS app. I've noticed the error again today...
